# how to stop musicplayer application from my application

Tags: android, audio-player, android-music-player

I am trying to make an application that stops the music player when the button is pressed?
everything works fine but i am not able to close the music player application? any suggestion or help....

Comment: which api's your using to play music.???

Comment: I am not using any api i just call the music player application from the click of a button. and i want that when the stop button is pressed the music player should stop playing songs.

Comment: if your opening music player application then you might have found stop or pause button thier.. ??

Comment: yes there is a pause button in the default music player but i want that my application should close or pause the music.